# Not able to add customfield value to Issue

Tags: python, jira-rest-api

```
res=issue.update(fields={"customfield_25361":[{"value":name}]})
print(res)



error:

response text = {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"customfield_25361":"data was not an object"}}
```

Adding the value to custom field to JIRA Issue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of the custom field?

Here is an example for updating component field:

```py
update = {
    "components": [
        {
            "add": {
                "name": str(NAME)
            }
        }
    ]
}
issue.update(notify=False, update=update)
```